# iOS renders table view cell background colors differently from button image colors, resulting in very differing shades of the same color

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

---

Update: this is not something specific to my app, I just re-created it with an Xcode template app. Its something iOS is doing - its rendering the cell and the button differently, resulting in them appearing with differing shades. Example project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j7eexzihs6swl3u/AAAuAzMVUKxzCkgPYsMaIYyHa?dl=0

I ran the project on the phone, took a screenshot then sampled the colors in Photoshop - the cell background comes out as 494a49 and the button comes out as 383938. So the color of the table view cell is being drastically altered.

---

I've got button with an image placed within in a cell of a table view. 
The cell content view background color is set to Ox383938 and the color of the background image set in the button is also 0x383938, yet they look very different:

[image]

Why is there such a difference in these two shades of gray?

The cell's grey is much paler, as it has an alpha of 0.7 or something while the button has an alpha of 1.0. But this is not the case - these are just a regular button and regular table view & cell dragged and dropped into the storyboard and nothing about them has been altered, nothing changed in the Storyboard settings etc. (other than the cell background color).

Whatever is making the cell paler than the image in the button has not been set by me, if its some default value in an image or button or row or table view then what and where is it and how can I make the cell background and button image the same shade exactly?

Comment: I guess you don't have the code that you could show us, since you use storyboards, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Milan Nosáľ yes Its all storyboard, no code. But see update - this is not something specific to my app.

Comment: then add a link to that template app, the easiest way for others to play around with it :)

Comment: @Milan Nosáľ. Will do once I've figured out where to host it, how to grant access, how to link to it etc.

Comment: just share it through dropbox

Comment: @Milan Nosáľ https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j7eexzihs6swl3u/AAAuAzMVUKxzCkgPYsMaIYyHa?dl=0

Comment: This does appear to be a bug in Xcode.  I downloaded your project and the colours were wrong as you say.  I then changed the background colour of the content view to yellow and then back to what it should be and this time it was correct.  Very strange indeed.

Comment: @Upholder Of Truth "..and then back to what it should be and this time it was correct." I'm not able to get it to correspond with the button image shade, I tried changing the background color but to no avail.

Comment: All I did was to select yellow in the colour list and then select something else.  Then select the content view again and change the hex value directly.

Comment: @Upholder Of Truth. That's not working for me, what version of Xcode do you have?

Comment: I'm using Version 9.2 (9C40b)

Comment: @Upholder Of Truth The same as me - so the mystery deepens.

Comment: It's because of the colour profile.  When you are editing by RGB sliders there is a settings cog next to the option dropdown.  If you set the colour profile to sRGB and then set the hex to the required values it should be correct.

Comment: when set programmatically, all works as should, seems @UpholderOfTruth found the cause

Comment: Yes that solves it. Thanks

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth create the answer to be accepted.. I'm not gonna steal your thunder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is down to the colour profile.  When you have the RGB sliders selected the settings cog will bring up a list of colour profiles and you have to match that to the image.  In this case it needs to be sRGB.  Then when you set the hex value it will match the image used on the button.